# Does Google App Engine have a production console (like heroku)?

Tags: google-app-engine, heroku

When working with Heroku I can open a console in production (`heroku console`), which makes it very easy to debug.

Is there something similar in Google App Engine?

(I can't just debug in development, because some third party libraries, e.g. Tweepy, only works in production)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for live debugging, the platform team released the Google Cloud debugger last year: https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger/

However, it currently only supports Java based appengine projects. Hopefully we will have python support this year...

In regards to live querying of a cloud project you have two options that are easily made available to any cloud project:

- There is the remote api which allows you to launch a shell to interact with appengine's api services and datastore. This also allows you to import / run application code remotely: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi
- There is also the appstats playground where you can run arbitrary python code in your environment of choice: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Comment: The remote api seems closes to heroku console to me. Basically we now can open a shell interacting with the remote app just like how we can open a shell interacting with our local app during development.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Heroku, so I don't know the full functionalities of the heroku console, but I know the App Engine has the [Developer console](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/developers-console/), which can provide you log, stacktraces, graphs about instances and usage.

You can access it at developers.google.com.

There also used to be appengine.google.com (still up with some functionalities) that provided other admin functions (like querying directly against your datastore). In that Admin console, you have a tab called "datastore viewer" which lets you query directly against the datastore. There are other nifty functionalities in there, but this older console will get deprecated soon. Most features should be re-added into the newer console over time.

Comment: I've been using the Developer console to view logs and database. But I was asking for the actual console, i.e. a command line where I can, say, query and modify database. Is there such a thing?

Comment: @Heisenberg you mean datastore?

Comment: @heisenberg, I will edit my answer shortly with something. Unfortunately, that other console is older and will soon be deprecated. I don't know if all the features will follow into the newer one

Comment: @Heisenberg there you go my friend, hope you find this to your liking

Answer (score 0):

yes if you using Google app engine with managed Vms you can access full functional console (either cmd line via ssh and web interface ).